# Meaning of "schon mal so richtig"

Tags: meaning, adverb

Kann jemand erklären, was »so richtig« in dem folgenden Satz bedeutet?

> Ist er jetzt schon mal so richtig in die Berge gegangen?

Auf Englisch übersetze ich das als

> Has he actually already been in the mountains?

aber es klingt ein bisschen falsch.

Comment: "Has he ever really..." or "earnestly"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*So richtig* ist ein verstärkendes umgangssprachliches Wortpaar. Es drückt aus, dass man nicht nur etwas tut, sondern es richtig, ausgiebig, ausführlich tut.

Wenn man *so richtig* in die Berge geht, dann fährt man nicht einfach nur nachmittags mit der Bahn nach Mittenwald und dann mit der Seilbahn auf den Karwendel, dreht eine Runde und fährt wieder heim. Man würde in der Früh losfahren, den Berg zu Fuß besteigen, vielleicht noch rüberkraxeln auf den Brunnenstein und erst spät abends wieder das Tal erreichen. (Disclaimer: Ich bin kein Bergsteiger, deswegen weiß ich nicht, ob diese Tour möglich/sinnvoll/kurz ist, sie scheint mir aber viel zu sein.)

*So richtig* impliziert immer, dass es eine »normale« oder »schwache« Art von einer Tätigkeit gibt, man selber aber die »ausgefallenere«, »anspruchsvollere«, »härtere« Art dieser Tätigkeit betreibt. Das Einsatzspektrum ist dabei fast unbegrenzt; man kann also zum Beispiel auch *so richtig chillen*, wenn man nicht einfach nur zehn Minuten sondern gleich den ganzen Tag lang nichts tut.

*Schon (ein)mal* ist übrigens davon völlig unabhängig und bedeutet, wie erwartet, *already* auf Englisch.

> Nur die Harten kommen in den Garten.
>
> Ey, warst du überhaupt schon mal so richtig im Garten?

Comment: Wer die letzten zwei Zeilen versteht, hat *so richtig* verstanden.

Comment: Wer die letzten zwei Zeilen versteht, hat **es** _so richtig_ verstanden, oder? ;)

Comment: Wenn schon, dann "richtig richtig verstanden"

Answer (score 1):

> Ist er jetzt schon mal so richtig in die Berge gegangen?

Je nachdem in welchem Zusammenhang der Satz gefallen ist, könnte "so richtig" die Bedeutung haben:

- wirklich, ernsthaft, tatsächlich
  English translation:

> Has he really/earnestly been in the mountains?

- so richtig tief/weit (entfernt) oder für längere Zeit. Beides bedeutet aber auch, dass man ernsthaft in den  Bergen war und nicht nur am Rande, wie @O.R.Mapper angemerkt hat 
  English translation (not sure whether this sounds correct in English at least in this context):

> Has he been really deep in the mountains yet?

English translation:

> Has he already been for a real long time in the mountains?

- endlich, mittlerweile, wirklich
  English translation:

> Has he finally been in the mountains?

- endlich, jemals richtig. Dies bedeutet natülich auch nur dass man wissen will ob er ernsthaft in den Bergen war aber mit dem Fokus, dass es überhaupt bzw. irgendwann einmal passiert ist/war!

  English translation:

> Has he (really) ever been in the mountains?

Die erste Variante ist wahrscheinlich die "universellere" bzw. wahrschinlichere!

Comment: Variante 2-4 schließe ich aus.

Comment: Ist Variante 4 nicht praktisch dasselbe wie Variante 1, und ist insbesondere Variante 2 nicht einfach eine konkretere Ausdrucksweise für Variante 1? Ich verstehe "wirklich, ernsthaft tatsächlich" jedenfalls als abstraktere Umschreibung dafür, dass man nicht nur am Gebirgsrand war (also tief drin) und auch nicht nur kurz durchgefahren ist, sondern sich dort "für längere Zeit" aufgehalten hat.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ganz unrecht hast du nicht, aber ich habe versucht den Fokus der Aussage etwas zu akzentuieren bzw. im Englischen!